# gitlab runner Job failed exit status 1 when running powershell commands

Tags: powershell, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a gitlab runner configured on windows 2019 server , with shell = powershell , I am trying to do a simple copy initially :

```
'''
- "$filezip = (Get-Date -f yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss)"
- compress-archive -path "\\test\release" -destinationpath "\\test\release\$filezip.zip"
- start-sleep -Seconds 10
- Remove-Item "\\test\release" -Exclude *.zip -force -recurse
- start-sleep -Seconds 10
- Robocopy "abc-folder" "\\test\release" /E /Z /xf *.config
- Robocopy "config-i" "\\test\release" /E /Z
- (get-service -ComputerName test -Name W32Time).Stop()
- start-sleep -Seconds 10
- compress-archive -path "\\test\abc-folder" -destinationpath "\\test\abc-folder\$filezip.zip"
- start-sleep -Seconds 10
- Remove-Item "\\test\abc-folder\*" -Exclude "log",*.zip,*.log -force -recurse
- start-sleep -Seconds 10
- Robocopy "\\test\abc-folder"  "\\test\abc-folder\archive"
- start-sleep -Seconds 10
- Robocopy "\\test\release" "\\test\abc-folder" /xf *.zip
- start-sleep -Seconds 10
- (get-service -ComputerName test -Name W32Time).Start()
- start-sleep -Seconds 10
```

its running using powershell , but when running using gitlab.ci its giving me error after Robocopy "abc-folder" "\test\release" /E /Z /xf *.config , although it copying the content successfully error :
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1.
gitlab-ci example :

````
  stage: deploy
  environment: dev
  when: manual
  script:
    - "$filezip = (Get-Date -f yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss)"
    - compress-archive -path "\\test\release" -destinationpath "\\test\release\$filezip.zip"
    - start-sleep -Seconds 10
    - Remove-Item "\\test\release" -Exclude *.zip -force -recurse
    - start-sleep -Seconds 10
    - Robocopy "abc-folder" "\\test\release" /E /Z /xf *.config
    - Robocopy "config-i" "\\test\release" /E /Z
    - (get-service -ComputerName test -Name W32Time).Stop()
    - start-sleep -Seconds 10
    - compress-archive -path "\\test\abc-folder" -destinationpath "\\test\abc-folder\$filezip.zip"
    - start-sleep -Seconds 10
    - Remove-Item "\\test\abc-folder\*" -Exclude "log",*.zip,*.log -force -recurse
    - start-sleep -Seconds 10
    - Robocopy "\\test\abc-folde"  "\\test\abc-folder\archive"
    - start-sleep -Seconds 10
    - Robocopy "\\test\release" "\\test\abc-folder" /xf *.zip
    - start-sleep -Seconds 10
    - (get-service -ComputerName test -Name W32Time).Start()
    - start-sleep -Seconds 10
  tags:
    - windows```




gitlab error:
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

               Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
    Dirs :         1         0         1         0         0         0
   Files :        33        33         0         0         0         2
   Bytes :   18.34 m   18.34 m         0         0         0    5.64 m
   Times :   0:00:03   0:00:03                       0:00:00   0:00:00


   Speed :             4945814 Bytes/sec.
   Speed :             283.001 MegaBytes/min.
   Ended : Thursday, May 19, 2022 5:33:28 AM

section_end:1652938408:step_script
[0Ksection_start:1652938408:cleanup_file_variables
[0K[0K[36;1mCleaning up project directory and file based variables[0;m[0;m
section_end:1652938409:cleanup_file_variables
[0K[31;1mERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
[0;m
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use powershell scripts rather than directly invoking , don't why it didn't work , but powershell scripts working okay i.e. calling  abc.ps1 from scripts section and abc.ps1 will consists of the powershell scripts/steps you want